# Sketch Plugin Development: Export Symbol as SVG Text

Tags: sketch-3, sketchapp, cocoa-scripting, cocoascript

I have a working example of exporting a selected symbol to an SVG string in Sketch 3. (Based on [this code](https://github.com/sketchplugins/plugin-requests/blob/master/Copy%20Layer%20as%20SVG.sketchplugin) from Sketch's GitHub)

The issue is the output is distorted and I'm unable to see the next logical step in troubleshooting.

### The Code

```js
// Get all symbols
var symbols = context.document.documentData().allSymbols();

// For purpose of this example, only get the first one for testing.
var symbol = symbols[0];

// Set a temporary file to save to. Necessary for generating the SVG
var tempPath = '/tmp/com.symbolui.sketch-commands/';
var guid = [[NSProcessInfo processInfo] globallyUniqueString];
var path = tempPath + guid;
[[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:path withIntermediateDirectories:true attributes:nil error:nil]

var export_path = path;
var export_filename = export_path + '/' + 'test.svg';

// do export
[doc saveArtboardOrSlice:frame toFile:export_filename];
var file_url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:export_filename];
var str = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:file_url];
```

At the final point in the code, `str` is a text value of the SVG generated from the symbol.

### The Output

Input Symbol:

[image]

Generated preview of SVG:

[image]

Generated SVG text:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<svg width="1200px" height="65px" viewBox="0 0 1200 65" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
<!-- Generator: Sketch 42 (36781) - http://www.bohemiancoding.com/sketch -->
<title></title>
<desc>Created with Sketch.</desc>
<defs>
    <rect id="path-1" x="0" y="0" width="49" height="20" rx="3"></rect>
    <mask id="mask-2" maskContentUnits="userSpaceOnUse" maskUnits="objectBoundingBox" x="0" y="0" width="49" height="20" fill="white">
        <use xlink:href="#path-1"></use>
    </mask>
</defs>
<g id="Symbols:-Labels" stroke="none" stroke-width="1" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd">
    <g id="Buttons" transform="translate(-422.000000, 31.000000)"></g>
    <g id="Label-/-Default" transform="translate(670.000000, 60.000000)">
        <use id="background" stroke="#979797" mask="url(#mask-2)" stroke-width="2" fill="#777777" xlink:href="#path-1"></use>
        <text id="-Default" font-family="HelveticaNeue-Bold, Helvetica Neue" font-size="10" font-weight="bold" fill="#FFFFFF">
            <tspan x="7" y="14">Default</tspan>
        </text>
    </g>
</g>
```

### Thoughts

As you can see the output is quite large in addition to being distorted. At the very least I believe I need to trim or rescale the symbol somehow. Where the distortion is coming through I have no idea.

Fixing the SVG markup itself isn't a solution - I'd like to see the solution in the Sketch plugin code. I'm finding documentation for internal Sketch code very difficult to work with and has been the big blocker for resolving this.

Comment: In case anyone else is curious.. I poured countless hours into SVG generation and had way too many bugs/inconsistencies. I ended up exporting temporary assets as PNG images, which for my use case was fine enough. I only needed preview images.

Answer (score 0):

you can convert the `MSSymbolInstance` to normal group, then export it.

```
if (layer.symbolMaster().children().count() > 1) {
    var tempSymbol = layer.duplicate(),
    tempGroup = tempSymbol.detachByReplacingWithGroup();

    tempGroup.resizeToFitChildrenWithOption(0);
    layer.setIsVisible(false);

    tempGroup.exportOptions().removeAllExportFormats();
    var format = tempGroup.exportOptions().addExportFormat();
    format.setFileFormat("SVG");

    var slice = MSExportRequest.exportRequestsFromExportableLayer(tempGroup).firstObject();
    var filePath = export_path + '/test.svg';
    doc.saveArtboardOrSlice_toFile(slice, filePath);
 }
```